# Counting number of rows using multiple clauses in Laravel Model

Tags: php, laravel

```
{{ App\Like::where('post_id', $post->id)->count() }}
```

I want to fetch rows which have particular post_id and whose 'like' column is set to 1. How can I put another clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{{ App\Like::where('post_id', $post->id)->where('like', 1)->count() }}
```

Just put another `where`